# How to make text function as clickable link in admin HTML / backend grid

Tags: php, adminhtml

I've created a custom extension that utilizes a grid to display a table of records. Inside those records there is a column known as *link* which contains a hyperlink to a specific webpage.

Currently I'm displaying this piece of text information with the following code inside of my grid.php extension file:

```
  $this->addColumn('link', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('myextension')->__('Link'),
      'align'     =>'left',
      'index'     => 'link',
  ));
```

It would pull whatever the user input into the custom form (e.g. "http://website.com"). All I want to do - inside of my grid.php file using the code above - is to wrap it the necessary code to make it render as a clickable link.

Render before:

```
<a href="
```

Render after:

```
">Link</a>
```

I tried concatenation which didn't work:

```
  $this->addColumn('link', '<a href="' . array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('myextension')->__('Link'),
      'align'     =>'left',
      'index'     => 'link',
  ) . '">Link</a>');
```

Any ideas?

Additional Notes: It is in fact an external link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deeperDATA,

**Using Format tag:**

You do this by  '`format`' tag in add add Column function Id

```
$this->addColumn('link', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('myextension')->__('Link'),
            'format'    => '<a href="http://website.com">Test</a>',
            'index'     => 'link',
            'sortable'  => false,
            'filter'    => false
        ));
```

**Using Render:**
you can do this by render concept  `'renderer'  => 'Your_Render_Class'`

```
$this->addColumn('link', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('myextension')->__('Link'),
            'index'     => 'link',
'renderer'  => 'Your_Render_Class'

));
```

**Then you need  create Rendered class**  which is  return the result of this column

```
< ?php
class Your_Render_Class extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
$value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
return '<a href="'.$value.'>amit</a>';
}

}
?>
```

Comment: That seems to put <a href="http://website.com">Test</a> into every field. Which is somewhat helpful but I need my unique data from the link column to be inside the href tag.

Comment: means ,cannot understand

Comment: are you want for each colums ya each row?

Comment: Yes, it's unique per row. There would be a different link per record.

Comment: is this link is comes from db or static logic?